# "Binlog has bad magic number" - recoverying InnoDB tables

Tags: mysql, innodb, wamp

A system crash raised the error in the title.

I've tried the suggestion [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27749/binlog-has-bad-magic-number), but then I can't access any of my InnoDB tables. They are still there, but data is missing. The provided solution probably messes with table index.

I was going to comment there to avoid duplicate, but I need 50 reputation for that.

I have a backup. So, how can I restore all InnoDB tables if I can't start mysql, dump and import?