# mysql master slave replication scenario

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6

We are creating a new mysql slave, but for dump we are taking from a backup server which is a slave of current master. Now to enable replication we want to connect it with the master so should I take log position from the master or from the backup server where i took the dump from.

Secondly the new server we have created is 5.6 and old server is 5.5, would there be any replication issues as well ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to setup slave from another slave steps would be as follows

- Flush tables with read lock to lock the slave so it should not get updates
- show slave status\G and note master co-ordinates
- Take backup now using mysqldump
- unlock tables to unlock the slave
- transfer that backup and restore it to new one
- Hope you have issues grant replication slave on master so need to use change master on the new slave and give co-ordinates noted in step-2

For details regarding master-slave version difference, shouldn't be a big issue but a good idea is to go through MySQL documentation.

Hope it helps

Comment: You still gets a +1 because your answer would be appropriate for MySQL 5.1/5.5 users.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 5.6, mysqldump can do that for you with [--dump-slave=1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_dump-slave) and [--single-transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction). It is the same as [--master-data=1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_master-data), but here is how the log file and position are retrieved:

- [--master-data=1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_master-data): log file and position from `SHOW MASTER STATUS;`
- [--dump-slave=1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_dump-slave): `Relay_Master_Log_File`,`Exec_Master_Log_Pos` from `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G`.

[--dump-slave=1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_dump-slave) will run do the following:

- `STOP SLAVE SQL_THREAD;`
- perform the dump
- `START SLAVE SQL_THREAD;`

No need to run `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;`

You also asked

> Secondly the new server we have created is 5.6 and old server is 5.5, would there be any replication issues as well ?

This is only one major issue that can break replication from 5.5 to 5.6

I discussed binlog format differences between versions (See [mysql replication master 5.5 slave 5.1 error on create database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87423/mysql-replication-master-5-5-slave-5-1-error-on-create-database/87438#87438))

In the case to MySQL 5.5 Master to MySQL 5.6 Slave, the issue my boss recently discovered has to do with the new TIMESTAMP format. MySQL 5.6 now supports microseconds in a TIMESTAMP. MySQL 5.5 does not. When doing row-based replication and Master and Slave have configured [binlog_format is either ROW or MIXED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_binlog-format), MySQL 5.6's IO Thread will replicate the MySQL 5.5 event, storing it in the relay. If the event contains a TIMESTAMP, MySQL 5.6's SQL Thread will break trying to unpack the event from the relay log.

The only workaround for this rare event is to set [binlog_format to STATEMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_binlog-format) on both Master and Slave. Then, set up replication.

## EPILOGUE

STEP 01 : Just run this on the current slave

```
mysqldump --dump-slave=1 --single-transaction ... > slave_data.sql
echo "START SLAVE;" >> slave_data.sql
```

STEP 02 : Move `slave_data.sql` to the new Slave server

STEP 03 : Run this on the new server

```
CHANGE MASTER TO
master_host='ipaddr_of_master',master_port=3306,
master_user='repluser',master_password='repluserpassword',
master_log_file='bin-log.000000',master_log_pos=4;
source slave_data.sql
```

This will setup replication and start it up for you.

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!