# enable log_bin_use_v1_row_events in mysql 5.6

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6

I have a MYSQL master with two slaves also running MYSQL 5.6. I want to create another slave and that needs to be MYSQL 5.5. I was wondering if replication will work smoothly.
I have  log_bin_use_v1_row_events switched off in MYSQL 5.6 and I am using mixed format replication.

Can anyone give me advise on doing above.

Answer (score 0):

There is one thing that cannot work with MySQL Replication from 5.5 to 5.6 : `DATETIME`. Why ?

MySQL 5.6 DATETIME has a very different byte format because it accommodates microseconds. When the [**binlog_format**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_binlog-format) is `ROW`, or when `MIXED` switches from `STATEMENT` to `ROW`, only a 5.6 Slave can unpack the row change from the relay logs. A slave running MySQL 5.5 cannot handle that.

I have two recent posts where I mentioned this

- `Jan 02, 2015` : [mysql replication master 5.5 slave 5.1 error on create database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87423/mysql-replication-master-5-5-slave-5-1-error-on-create-database/87438#87438)
- `Jun 18, 2015` : [mysql master slave replication scenario](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/104451/mysql-master-slave-replication-scenario/104474#104474)

The workaround I learned from my boss back in January was to switch [**binlog_format**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_binlog-format) to `STATEMENT` and restart mysqld.

If you enable [**log_bin_use_v1_row_events**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_log_bin_use_v1_row_events) on a MySQL 5.6 Master to let a MySQL 5.5 slave read it, that sounds like it could work. I still worry about the `DATETIME` representation. If you set the option [**log_bin_use_v1_row_events**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_log_bin_use_v1_row_events) to true and it stops MySQL 5.6 from writing microseconds with [**binlog_format**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_binlog-format) `ROW` or `MIXED`, then you I think have something. Based on my two posts, I cannot guarantee other statements would be immune.

I would normally say "GIVE IT A TRY !!!" but I have never tried that [**log_bin_use_v1_row_events**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_log_bin_use_v1_row_events). So, go ahead and try and let us know.